# Body and headers dissapear when making HTTP requests from Flutter web with Dio

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I have been using the [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package as an alternative to [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) on flutter mobile for a while, and it has been working fine. When I tried it on flutter web however, it does not work as expected.

When looking at the request on the server side the body is completely empty, and the header parameters that I added are also gone. The issue is the same using both post and get.

The code that sends the request looks like below:

```dart
final dio = Dio();

dio.interceptors.add(
  InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
      if (options.path != 'login')
        options.headers.addAll({
          'authorization': jwt,
        });
      options.baseUrl = 'http://192.168.1.168:8080/';
      options.responseType = ResponseType.json;
      return handler.next(options);
    },
    onError: (DioError error, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
      maybeRefreshToken(error, handler, refreshToken);
    },
  ),
);

Future login(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    final response = await dio.post(
      'login',
      data: {
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
      },
    );
    Tokens tokens = Tokens.fromJson(response.data);
    jwt = tokens.token;
    refreshJwt = tokens.refreshToken;
  } catch (error) {
    throw parseError(error);
  }
}
```

I have tried to make the same request with the http package and that works, so I'm quite certain that the problem has something to do with Dio.